# Properly collapse and rebuild nested models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model with nested collections and models.

I was using backbone-relational to automatically build the nested models but found out that when setting data on an existing parent model it creates the nested models in place of the existing ones, it doesn't update them.

Now that I figured this out I need to figure out the best way to collapse and rebuild backbone models that contain nested collections/models.

Any pointers would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use this solution that I rebuilt in CoffeeScript from an example by Henrik Joreteg.

```
# builds and return a simple object ready to be JSON stringified
xport: (opt) ->
    result = {}
    settings = _({recurse: true}).extend(opt || {})

    process = (targetObj, source) ->

        targetObj.id = source.id || null
        targetObj.cid = source.cid || null
        targetObj.attrs = source.toJSON()

        _.each source, (value, key) ->
            # since models store a reference to their collection
            # we need to make sure we don't create a circular refrence
            if settings.recurse
                if (key isnt 'collection' && source[key] instanceof Backbone.Collection)

                    targetObj.collections = targetObj.collections || {}
                    targetObj.collections[key] = {}
                    targetObj.collections[key].models = []
                    targetObj.collections[key].id = source[key].id || null

                    _.each source[key].models, (value, index) ->
                        process(targetObj.collections[key].models[index] = {}, value)

                else if (source[key] instanceof Backbone.Model)

                    targetObj.models = targetObj.models || {}
                    process(targetObj.models[key] = {}, value)

    process(result, @)

    return result


#rebuild the nested objects/collections from data created by the xport method
mport: (data, silent) ->

    process = (targetObj, data) ->
        targetObj.id = data.id || null
        targetObj.set(data.attrs, {silent: silent})

        # loop through each collection
        if data.collections

            _.each data.collections, (collection, name) ->
                targetObj[name].id = collection.id
                                    #Skeleton stores a raw id reference to the object for updating
                Skeleton.models[collection.id] = targetObj[name]

                _.each collection.models, (modelData, index) ->
                    newObj = targetObj[name]._add({}, {silent: silent})
                    process(newObj, modelData)  

        if data.models
            _.each data.models, (modelData, name) ->
                process(targetObj[name], modelData)

    process(@, data)

    return @
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define what gets rendered and what does not get rendered on a data change for a view.  You could make sure the event you bind to for 'change' only renders what you want.  You can also bind to events for changes of just certain attributes as well.  You don't have to just use an all encompassing 'change'.

```
object.bind('change:attribute', callback);
```

Comment: Thanks, yea I know that. There is a generic model sync via websockets that needs to be triggered when anything changes. So if the model is throwing add/change events when nothing has changed it's a problem. The syncing needs to stay generic too so it can handle all different models.